# When I run the application it runs on two ports

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, port

I'm developing a web app with C#. Whenever I run the application using Visual Studio, two browser tabs open and the application runs on two ports: one of them is the correct one - the one with a portnumber that I specified. The other is unwanted and its portnumber is different every time I run it (I think VS looks at the next available port).

Does anyone know where the latter can be configured? I only want the application to run on the specified portnumber.

This is part of launchSettings.json where I've specified the sslPort:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
     "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44646",
     "sslPort": 44368
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Cassys.App": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
     "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

The port 44368 works and is correct. But  somehow another browser-tab is opened with a different portnumber every time.

Edit: as requested by @Zhi Lv in comment section, here's the launch.json:

```
{
linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/WebApi.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "localhost:44368"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
         },
        {
             "name": ".NET Core Attach",
             "type": "coreclr",
             "request": "attach",
             "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: any chance it may come from "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44646" part?

Comment: 44646 and 44368... that's two ports, isn't it?

Comment: this happened if you configure you application to enable SSL first port for http and another one for https

Comment: I believe the point is that the SSL port opens in its own tab, but 44646 does not; that is replaced with a randomly-assigned port number.

Comment: There are many protocols that use more than one port.  Many secure application will use a main port for command and control while the actual secure data will be sent on another port number to make it harder for hackers to capture the data.  Your launch settings has two port numbers 44646 and 44368.

Comment: @GrumpyMonk: Can you update your post to include whole the `launchSettings.json` configuration file, please?

Comment: I've figured out that when I disable SSL it takes the port from 'applicationUrl' from launchSettings AND it opens another browser-tab with a generated portnumber. If SSL is enabled it takes the port from 'sslPort' from launchSettings AND it opens another browser-tab with a generated portnumber.

Comment: @Jackdaw the full launchSettings.json has been added to the post

Comment: @GrumpyMonk don't disable SSL. Almost all web sites use HTTPS for security reasons. HTTPS is a requirement for HTTP/2 as well. This means that almost all web sites use two ports - one for HTTP and one for HTTPS. The HTTP endpoint is only meant to handle HTTP calls by redirecting to the HTTPS endpoint

Comment: @GrumpyMonk in fact, most browsers use HTTPS by default when you type an address these days

Comment: @OlivierRogier Only the first one (44646) is used. What I mean is that the application opens a browser with this port, but the second portnumber is generated on launch. When I change the applicationUrl to contain the same port as the ssl port I get the error "unable to connect to web server iis express" when I try to run it.

Comment: Hi @GrumpyMonk, Perhaps the issue is related to the VS Code launch configuration, can you post the launch.json content? Besides, in the launch.json file, try to add `"ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5050"` in the `env` node. code like this: ` "env": { "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",  "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5050" },`, it will open the website using 5050 port.

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv, As you requested I've added the launch.json to the post. I've also added the "ASPNETCORE_URLS" to the launch.json. Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue